# _id is undefined even though it's right there in console.log(object)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I can do a console log and get company. It has _id as an object property.

```
$scope.add2 = function () {
  if (!$scope.company2) $scope.company2 = [];

  var company2 = new Companies({
    name: 'FestivalSauce',
    store: 'DePereYo',
  });

  company2.$save(function (response) {
    $scope.company2.push(response);
  });

  console.log(company2);       
};
```

This is what I get in console

```
Resource {name: "FestivalSauce", store: "DePereYo", toJSON: function, $get: function, $save: function…}
$promise: undefined
$resolved: true
__v: 0
_id: "5462f632b85133000023c1ba"
name: "FestivalSauce"
store: Array[1]
__proto__: Resource
```

If I change console.log(company2._id) I get 'undefined' in console. Doesn't make sense.

Update: Here's the proto
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4aof.png

Comment: It looks like the name of the property is `0_id` not `_id`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! I recognize your name :) I checked at 0 is just the value for _v.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you show the code for its prototype the `Resource`, and the constructor `Companies`? Usually `_` is used to denote that the property is private. Maybe they used some new ES6 features to make it inaccessible. It is hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Sure thing. There's the option to expand even more text in some of these. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Okay, I added an image http://i.imgur.com/ecja6ev.png

Comment: `company2.$save()` is asynchronous, and will create the `._id` property only after you try to log it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that `company2` is actually an array. It's confusing because you're mixing objects and arrays. I bet if you try `console.log(company2[0]._id)`, it will display `5462f632b85133000023c1ba`.

I'd be interested to see the definition of `Companies` to confirm.

Comment: Oh man, this kept me from being stuck forever. The find() method in Mongoose and MongoDB returns an array, even if there is just one record.  Duh. I just oversaw the array brackets in the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

`company2` doesn't seem to be a plain object with `_id` as its property. You can however try converting it to JSON. You can try `console.log(company2.toJSON()._id)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, Munim! It's still saying undefined when I add toJSON() in there. In my brackets IDE text editor, it auto suggests _id for company2._id, but it just shows up as undefined in the browser console for some reason.

Comment: I expanded the __proto__ if that helps solve the question with more information http://i.imgur.com/ecja6ev.png